# Emberfire destroyRecord error

Tags: ember.js, firebase, ember-data, emberfire

I am currently receiving `todo is not defined` when I try to call the `destoryRecord` method on an item in my store. I have tried to rewrite this code a number of ways but i still seem to be running into problems.

Here are the files I am working with. It posts records just fine, but I just keep running into a problem with deleting them.

```
// todo/controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        createTodo: function() {
            this.store.createRecord('todo', {
            name: this.get('name'),
            createdAt: new Date()
        });
        this.set('name', '');
        },
        removeTodo: function() {
        this.store.find('todo', todo).then(function(todo) {
            todo.destroyRecord();
            });
        }
    }
});





// todo/model.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date')
});



// todo/route.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('todo');
     }
   });

// todo/template.hbs
{{outlet}}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2 class="text-center">Add a Todo!</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <label for="Todo">Add a Todo!</label>
    {{input value=name placeholder="Add a Todo"}}
   <button class="btn btn-default" {{action "createTodo"}}>Publish</button> 
    </div>
    {{#each model as |todo|}}
        <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
    <li>
        <button class="btn btn-default" {{action "removeTodo"}}>x</button>  
    {{todo.name}}</li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe emberfire does not support pod structure ? have you tried placing model inside default `app/models`

Comment: @Bek I set `usePods` to `true` in the .ember-cli file. The question was answered below thought. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `removeTodo` function has a problem, the `todo` variable passed to the `find` function is not defined anywhere.

```
removeTodo: function() {
    this.store.find('todo', todo /* Where is this coming from */).then(function(todo) {
        todo.destroyRecord();
        });
    }
```

You need the following changes to the template:

```
{{action "removeTodo" todo}}
```

The previous changes makes the `todo` which is available in the `each` as `|todo|` to be passed to the action `removeTodo`

And you need to change the `removeTodo` function to this

```
removeTodo: function(todo) {
    todo.destroyRecord();
}
```

Now that it receives the `todo` used in the context of the iteration you can use it in the function and call `destroyRecord` on it.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Pretty silly of me to get caught up on that but now I know for next time! Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad I could help. It's frequently a little detail that we for some reason don't see (and having other people look helps). Best of luck with your ember app!